# Flattening of List[List[Int]] whilst retaining only selected members

Tags: scala, scala-collections

There is a List[List[Int]] of prime factors for integers 2..12:

```
List(List(2), List(3), List(2, 2), List(5), List(3, 2), 
     List(7), List(2, 2, 2), List(3, 3), List(5, 2), 
     List(11), List(3, 2, 2))
```

It needs to be flattened so that the resulting data structure contains only the longest sequence (greatest power) of each prime:

```
List(2,2,2,3,3,5,7,11)
```

For example, leaving out all but the greatest power of two:
List(List(<strike>2</strike>), List(3), List(<strike>2, 2</strike>), List(5), List(3<strike>, 2</strike>), 
         List(7), List(**2, 2, 2**), List(3, 3), List(5<strike>, 2</strike>), 
         List(11), List(3<strike>, 2, 2</strike>))

Within the initial list sub-lists of primes are always sorted in the descending order.

Struggling to find an elegant, preferably ≤O(n) solution.

My solution is far from ideal:

```
xs.flatMap(l=> l.groupBy(x=>x)).map(x=>(x._1,x._2.length)).
   groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.maxBy(_._2)).values.
   map(x=>List.fill(x._2) (x._1)).flatten
```

Comment: I don't think you can get any better than O(N), you'll need to traverse all the lists, how can you do that in less than O(N)?

Comment: @zmbq, you're right, fixed. It's only a nice to have though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis the problem boils down to a simple merge of two sorted lists, but with a slight twist - it must add duplicate elements only once:

```
merge(List(5,3,3,2),List(7,5,3,2,2)
```

Must produce:

```
List(7,5,3,3,2,2)
```

Once there is such wonderful `merge` function the list of lists can be simply reduced from left to right.

**Solution**

```
def merge (xs:List[Int],ys:List[Int]):List[Int] = (xs,ys) match{
  case (Nil,_)         => ys
  case (_,Nil)         => xs
  case (x::xxs,y::yys) => if (x==y) x::merge(xxs,yys) 
                          else if (x>y) x::merge(xxs,ys) 
                          else y::merge(xs,yys)
}

// note the simplicity of application
ll reduce merge
```

**Tail recursive version of `merge` - avoiding stack overflow on long lists :**

```
def merge (xs:List[Int],ys:List[Int]) = {
  def m (rs:List[Int],xs:List[Int],ys:List[Int]):List[Int] = (xs,ys) match {
    case (Nil,_)         => ys reverse_:::rs
    case (_,Nil)         => xs reverse_:::rs
    case (x::xxs,y::yys) => if (x==y) m(x::rs,xxs,yys) 
                            else if (x>y) m(x::rs,xxs,ys) 
                            else m(y::rs,xs,yys)
  }

  m(Nil,xs,ys).reverse   
}
```

**Faster imperative version of `merge`:**

```
def merge (x:List[Int],y:List[Int]) = {
  var rs = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
  var xs = x
  var ys = y
  while(!xs.isEmpty && !ys.isEmpty) {
    if (xs.head>ys.head) {
      rs+=xs.head
      xs=xs.tail
    } else if(xs.head==ys.head) {
      rs+=xs.head
      xs=xs.tail
      ys=ys.tail
    } else {
      rs+=ys.head
      ys=ys.tail          
    }
  }
  rs ++= xs ++= ys toList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fair bit shorter than what you have; it's close enough conceptually that I expect you can figure it out:

```
xs.flatMap(_.groupBy(x=>x)).groupBy(_._1).
  flatMap(_._2.sortBy(- _._2.length).head._2).toSeq.sorted
```

Comment: this not much different on the qualitative level - alright for one-off scripting scenarios, but so is my initial clumsy solution.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder, of course, but this isn't bad IMO.  It's brief and it gets the job done.  You didn't specify what exactly you want.  If the Scala library had counted sets, it'd be easy.  Custom merges work too, as you've shown, if you're willing to write a much longer solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
val ll = List(List(2), List(3), List(2, 2), List(5), List(3, 2),  
     List(7), List(2, 2, 2), List(3, 3), List(5, 2), 
     List(11), List(3, 2, 2))
val s = ll.flatten toSet 
s.map (n => ll.map (l => (n, l.count (_ == n)))).map (l => (l(0) /: l.tail) ((a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b))
```

produces:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = Set((7,1), (11,1), (2,3), (5,1), (3,2))
```

expanding the factors and sorting them, to generate  List (2,2,2,3,3,5,7,11) is left as an exercise.

Comment: `.map(x=>List.fill(x._2) (x._1)).flatten` will do the job